# Slow lookup of realm object using realm js

Tags: javascript, performance, react-native, ecmascript-6, realm

Realm is known to be a fast local storage for mobile developers to deal with data persistence. But when I query information from local realm js in my react-native app, it's quite slow to get the value of a data field after querying the `realmObject`.

For example, define a schema as follow:

```
export const userSchema = {
  name: 'User',
  primaryKey: 'id',
  properties: {
    id: 'string',
    age: 'int',
    height: 'float',
    weight: 'float',
    gender: 'int',
  }
}
```

You stored some instances already, now you also queried some instances out. Then you have a `Proxy` of a list of `realmObject`. Performance is not a issue till now. Then you iterate over the `Proxy` using a loop or whatever, try to get weight from each instance. This is the part that the performance starts to drastically drop:

[image]

As you can see from the above performance profiling, to get the `weight` from a realm object, the time elapsed is significantly more than the time to get the `weight` from a plain json object. Why is this so slow?

Comment: I encounter the same issue. Do u have a solution for this issue?

Comment: Same problem here. Is it only in the debugger ?

Comment: I've also posted to the issue trackers here, seems like they haven't solved the problems yet. https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/1721

Comment: Did you find a solution? same issue here

Comment: @Rubycon Not yet, if you check the issue tracker I provided above, it is still an open issue.